# For the following, determine whether the set $S$ is a subspace of the vector space $V$

Tags: linear-algebra, polynomials, vector-spaces

$$ V=P_3, \qquad S= \left\lbrace(x + ax^2):a\in\mathbb R\right\rbrace. $$

Why is set not a subspace? The answer says that $S$ is not closed under scalar multiplication.

Comment: Should there be no coefficient before the linear term?

Comment: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)

Answer (score 2):

Take $x + ax^2 \in S$.

Is

$$2 \cdot (x + ax^2) = 2x + 2ax^2$$ also an element of $S$?

Comment: Ah. So, if we S was (ax+ax^2) then we would have S closed under scalar multiplication?

Comment: Yes, this would be closed by scalar multiplication.